# Are Linux's timezone files always in /usr/share/zoneinfo?

Tags: linux, timezone

I'm writing a program that needs to be able to read in the time zone files on Linux. And that means that I need to be able to consistently find them across distros. As far as I know, they are always located in /usr/share/zoneinfo. The question is, are they in fact *always* located in /usr/share/zoneinfo? Or are there distros which put them elsewhere? And if so, where do they put them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quote from `tzset(3)`:

> The system timezone directory used depends on the (g)libc version. 
>   Libc4 and libc5 use /usr/lib/zoneinfo,
>   and,  since  libc-5.4.6,
>   when  this  doesn't  work,  will  try  /usr/share/zoneinfo. 
>   Glibc2 will use the environment
>   variable TZDIR, when that exists.  Its
>   default depends on how it was installed, but normally is
>   /usr/share/zoneinfo.

Note, however, that nothing prevents some perverse distro from patching libc and placing the files wherever they want.

Answer (score 1):

[The public-domain time zone database](https://www.iana.org/time-zones) contains the code and data to handle time zones on Linux.

> The public-domain time zone database
> contains code and data that represent
> the history of local time for many
> representative locations around the
> globe. It is updated periodically to
> reflect changes made by political
> bodies to time zone boundaries, UTC
> offsets, and daylight-saving rules.
> This database (often called tz or
> zoneinfo) is used by several
> implementations, including the GNU C
> Library used in GNU/Linux, FreeBSD,
> NetBSD, OpenBSD, Cygwin, DJGPP, AIX,
> Mac OS X, OpenVMS, Oracle Database,
> Solaris, Tru64, and UnixWare.

That covers a lot of system but I can only agree with Roman that nobody can be prevented from creating a distribution that differs for whatever reasons. The existence and location of a zonezinfo file is not covered by any official standard as far as I know. The standards (e.g. POSIX and XPG4) only establish the API.